# Why CSS by rem unit and border-radius can't make a circle

Tags: css

I'm using rem unit for my project. I set a block `width` and `height` equal, and border radius 50%. But block does not make a circle.

Here is the code

```css
.khXSxJ:before {
    content: "";
    display: block;
    width: 0.8rem;
    height: 0.8rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    margin-top: -0.4rem;
    left: 2rem;
    background-color: #00BCCA;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

And then the result

[image: css border radius]

And here is the computed value

[image]

When I set it to 8px for both dimension (My root font size is 62.5%), it works. So why this strange behavious

Updated: 2021/11/20 My font size is 60%, not 62.5% and this may be a bug by Google Chrome (Firefox & Safari work well). In Chrome, I have to set root font exact 62.5% to get this expect behaviour.

Comment: I don't see a problem (Edge/Chrome and Firefox on Windows10 laptop). What system are you using? However, using fractions of CSS pixels can cause problems when the system has to map them to the several screen pixels representing one CSS pixel. I don't think it's related to rem. Can you try setting  height and width in pixels at 7.67188px and see if the problem is still there. I expect it to be.

Comment: @AHaworth thank for you suggestion. I figured out it may a bug by chrome. Firefox and Safari work as I expect. My root font-size current ly set 60%, not 62.5%, Google Chrome only works when root font-size exact 62.5%, so strange

Comment: Would it better just to set border-radius to 100vw?

Comment: If you put an SO snippet in your question which shows the problem it may make it easier for people to help as the code shown isn’t enough to give the non circles on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I have noticed this exact same problem when using values other than px. Instead of a circle i get an oval, even though i have border-radius either set to 9999px or 50%. The solution for me is just to use an iconfont which has a circle in it (or draw one in Inkscape yourself and drag-drop into fontello.com), or use a svg image instead of hard-coded css dot.